# MySQL Unable to connect to remote host

Tags: database, mysql, telnet

I am just wasting too much time with this issue. My final goal is to change the collation of the Amazon RDS DB from latin to utf8. To accomplish that, there is a lot of information out there, and yet, non of that has worked for me.

First of all I tried to prompt mysql:

```
mysql -h ###.###.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p --port=3306
```

but it raise an `ERROR 2003 (HY000):  Can't connect to MySQL server on '###.###.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)`

If I try using telnet:

```
telnet ###.###.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
Trying 54.###.##.##...
telnet: connect to address 54.###.##.##: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Looking at the [aws.docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.html) says that I have to authorize access to my cache cluster. But I could't get that far. I didn't know what to put on the `Port range`and `Source` by trying to add a new `Custom TCP rule` for my `default security group`. So I ended following [this tutorial using mysqldump](http://bdunagan.com/2011/09/29/converting-mysql-from-latin1-to-utf8/) but I have the same connection problem as using >mysql

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: probably a firewall blocking 3306 access. if 3306 wasn't firewalled but mysql also wasn't listening on the port, you'd get connection refused. "connection timed out" means something's dropping the packets, which hints it's a firewall actively dropping the packets. And note that unless you've made typo, MySQL's port is 33 ZERO SIX. You're using 33 SIXTY on your telnet test

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I don't think so because I don't have any proxy or firewall specification, but let me check...

Comment: According to ipfw, the firewall is turned off. And yes, it was a type with telnet's port.